# Unable to find the OUTFILE of mysql query

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

I have an MySql query from which i generate a OUTFILE (.csv) which i save it in /tmp . Please find the query below :

```
SELECT 'Artifact ID' id, 'Related Links' new_value UNION select CONCAT(si.ID_PREFIX, si.ID_COUNT) as ID, tmp.NEW_VALUE from ( select ACTIVITY_ID, ISSUE_ID, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE from SCARAB_ACTIVITY where ISSUE_ID in (select ISSUE_ID from SCARAB_ISSUE where MODULE_ID = 775)  and (NEW_VALUE like 'http%') order by ACTIVITY_ID desc) tmp, SCARAB_ISSUE si where tmp.ISSUE_ID = si.ISSUE_ID INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/flexsustain_test_relatedlinks.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '' TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I have already tried to configure /etc/my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /var/lib/mysql/tmp
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
read-only = 0
```

and also i gave full permissions to tmpdir. But when i run the query not sure where the file is saved. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you show the query that you used for this?

Comment: @StefanR please find the query below :

SELECT 'Artifact ID' id, 'Related Links' new_value UNION select CONCAT(si.ID_PREFIX, si.ID_COUNT) as ID, tmp.NEW_VALUE from ( select ACTIVITY_ID, ISSUE_ID, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE from SCARAB_ACTIVITY where ISSUE_ID in (select ISSUE_ID from SCARAB_ISSUE where MODULE_ID = 775)  and (NEW_VALUE like 'http%') order by ACTIVITY_ID desc) tmp, SCARAB_ISSUE si where tmp.ISSUE_ID = si.ISSUE_ID INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/flexsustain_test_relatedlinks.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '' TERMINATED BY ',';

Comment: Please update it to the question.

Comment: @StefanR i have updated it

Comment: You have configured tmpdir to be /var/lib/mysql/tmp, but you save the file under /tmp in that query. Did you check from /tmp ?

Comment: @StefanR ok got your point, actually i used to save it the same way on another server and the file used to save in a different system directory.
Now its clear. Thanks

Comment: Ok.. i'll write it as an answer.. Can you mark it as correct then?

Comment: @StefanR yes i have checked /tmp, i dont see anything there.

but on a different server with the same configuration if i save, the file used too get saved in some "systemd-private../tmp/" directory

Comment: Can you check with find, if that file exists "find / -type f -iname 'flexsustain_test_relatedlinks.csv' "

Comment: @StefanR sure, i will mark it

Comment: @StefanR i have already check that , no results.
you can go ahead and post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified `/var/lib/mysql/tmp` as temporary directory in your configuration for the database server, but you did specify in the query that the file should be saved under `/tmp`. So you should find the file resulting from that query under the `/tmp` directory.

But if you are using a server with systemd and you have privatetemp enabled for db, then that file probably will be stored under a privatetemp folder even if you specify absolute path in the query. Private temp folder will be something like `/tmp/systemd-mariadb.service-XXXXXXX/tmp/outfile.csv`.